# making multiplication table by using do while loop with excel vba

Tags: excel, matrix-multiplication, vba

I am trying to do 2 dimension dynamic multiplication table by using "do while loop" but I can get only 1 row with this code can someone help? and i need to use do while loop not another loop.

```
Sub multp_doWhileLoop()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim l As Long
k = Range("b1").Value
l = Range("d1").Value
ReDim multp_tab(k, l) As Long 'defining ixj matrix
i = 1
j = 1
Range("a2:zz100000").Clear
Cells(2, 1) = "mult."
    Do While i < k + 1
        Do While j < l + 1
        Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = i       'for frame
        Cells(2, j + 1).Value = j       '
        multp_tab(i, j) = i * j
        j = j + 1

       Loop
       i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 1
    j = 1
        Do While i < k + 1
            Do While j < l + 1
            Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value = multp_tab(i, j)
            j = j + 1

            Loop
        i = i + 1
        Loop      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tell me that you aren't getting help from me to cheat on your exams.

```
Sub multp_doWhileLoop()
    ' 09 Apr 2017

    Dim Mtbl As Variant                     ' Multiplication table
    Dim R As Long                           ' row
    Dim C As Long                           ' column
    Dim Rmax As Long                        ' try to give meaning to the names
    Dim Cmax As Long                        ' you give to your variables

    With ActiveSheet
        Rmax = .Cells(1, "B").Value
        Cmax = .Cells(1, "D").Value
        If Rmax < 1 Or Cmax < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter valid parameters in row 1.", _
                   vbExclamation, "Invalid matrix parameters"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ReDim Mtbl(1 To Rmax, 1 To Cmax)    'defining ixj matrix

        Do
            R = R + 1
            C = 0
            Do
                C = C + 1
                Mtbl(R, C) = R * C
            Loop While C < Cmax
        Loop While R < Rmax

        With .UsedRange
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents
        End With
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Rmax, Cmax).Value = Mtbl
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No it is not for my exam. I am trying to understand other loops with same problem.I did it with for loop but couldnt do this one. Thank you for help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a short solution:

```
Sub multp()    
    For c = 1 To 10
       For r = 1 To 10
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(r, c).Value = r * c
       Next r
    Next c    
End Sub
```